# Can someone identify this honeysuckle plant by the flowers?

Tags: identification, flowers, vines, honeysuckle

*Click for original picture context*

[image]

Can someone please tell me what type of honeysuckles these are?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [*Lonicera japonica*, Japanese Honeysuckle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lonicera_japonica). Of course, I can't see the entire plant so I have to go entirely by the flower form and from what I can see of the leaves. *Lonicera japonica* is considered invasive in much of North America.