# What is this vine with clusters of black berries, found in Southern Illinois?

Tags: identification, weeds, vines, invasive

I've been working on controlling the edge of my backyard, since it borders a wooded area, and there's a bunch of invasive vines growing everywhere. While I was chopping back some of the underbrush, I noticed that on one of the bushes there was a vine that has berries on it.

I thought it was a shrub at first, but when I looked at it again, I noticed that it was actually a vine running around the shrub. The vine has pairs of rounded leaves running along each side of if, with clusters of small black berries running along it at about 4-inch intervals.

I live in Southern Illinois, Zone 6.

Here are some pictures (Click for full-size):

[image]  
[image]

I don't know if this view helps at all. It's kind of in the mix of a bunch of vines.

[image]

Comment: Different question, but similar: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14387/can-someone-identify-this-honeysuckle-plant-by-the-flowers

Comment: I am in Missouri and I have these all over the fence line in my backyard. Always wondered what these were so it sounds like we both have a Japanese honeysuckle invasion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that's Japanese honeysuckle, or [*Lonicera japonica*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lonicera_japonica). It's a very common invasive vine that spreads by the black berries, and by runner above and below ground. Here are pictures of the flowers and berries:

[image]
  [image]